# Updating an object using efcore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I was creating a UpdateEntityCommand and I wanted to make it flex. If some properties are null then these properties are not modified and they will have the same value before. I've done it with using Reflection. However I am not that sure that this is wise way to do it. These are my entities and codes.

Drink

```
public class Drink : Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string? Explanation { get; set; }
    public double? Calories { get; set; }
    public bool HasStock { get; set; } = true;
    public int? Volume { get; set; }
    public int DrinkCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual DrinkCategory DrinkCategory { get; set; }

}
```

UpdateDrinkDto

```
public class UpdateDrinkDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public bool? HasStock { get; set; } = true;
    public string? Explanation { get; set; }
    public int? Volume { get; set; }
}
```

And the methods

```
public async Task<DrinkDto> Handle(UpdateDrinkCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Drink ?drink = await _drinkRepository.GetAsync(x => x.Id == request.UpdateDrinkDto.Id, x => x.Include(x=>x.DrinkCategory).ThenInclude(x=>x.Menu));
            _drinkBusinessRules.DoesDrinkExists(drink);
            await _businessRules.IsOwnerResponsibleForRestaurant(request.OwnerId, drink.DrinkCategory.Menu.RestaurantId);

            SetProperties(request.UpdateDrinkDto, drink);

            Drink updatedDrink = await _drinkRepository.UpdateAsync(drink);

            DrinkDto response = _mapper.Map<DrinkDto>(updatedDrink);

            return response;





        }

        private void SetProperties(UpdateDrinkDto updateDrinkDto, Drink drink)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(UpdateDrinkDto).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (updateDrinkDto.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(updateDrinkDto) != null) typeof(Drink).GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(drink, property.GetValue(updateDrinkDto));
            }
        }
```

It works as I want it. However I want to learn is there any other way to implement this look. Thank you

Comment: Short answer: no. At least, nothing out of the box. Note that this prevents you from setting properties to null, which may be a problem for non-string properties (strings can be set to en empty string).